# What is the convention for @BeforeClass (@BeforeAll) and @AfterClass (@AfterAll) method names?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, junit5

Historically, there is a popular convention in JUnit, to name:

- `@Before`/`@BeforeEach` methods as `setUp()`
- `@After`/`@AfterEach` methods as `tearDown()`

How about `@BeforeClass`/`@BeforeAll` and `@AfterClass`/`@AfterAll` method names? is there any adopted naming convention?

I could not find any credible resource on this.

Comment: This might sound silly but I name them `beforeEach`, `beforeAll`, and so on. I mean, it's simple. Why bother with more complicated names.

Comment: So, you deviate from `setUp()`? I don't think it sounds silly, on the contrary - I, sort of, like it; however, I just want to know whether there is an adopted convention on this. Some perfectionist's peculiarity.

Comment: Yes I don't follow `setUp`/`tearDown`, I keep the annotation names. You know, sometimes conventions become so because of legacy code, not because they're actually good.

Comment: [official tutorial](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/) does not use those `setUp/tearDown` neither in the current version.  I bet someone (years ago before `stackoverflow` existed), used such an example on sun forums and coderanch and everyone just used those since then.

Comment: @Eugene might be.. but the fact is, that today, it's a "defacto" standard. Even popular tools and IDEs scaffold the code with those names.. if there is, at least, some *convention* on `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach`, there should be something for `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll`. Wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setUp()` and `tearDown()` only exist as *conventions* because those were the hard coded names of the methods in JUnit 3's [`TestCase`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/javadoc/junit/framework/TestCase.html). Thus, prior to JUnit 4 those methods had to be named exactly that.

Since JUnit 4, developers are free to name setup and tear-down methods anything they want. The same applies to JUnit Jupiter.

Some people prefer to continue to name them `setUp()` and `tearDown()`. Some people prefer to simply name them after the annotations, such as `before()`/`beforeEach()` and `after()`/`afterEach()`. Some people prefer to name them something meaningful like `prepareMock()` and `verifyMockInvocations()`.

So, in the end it's really just a matter of preference.

JUnit 3 did not have class-level lifecycle callback methods. Consequently, there are no corresponding legacy conventions like with `setUp()` and `tearDown()`. As for what to call them, the same "preference rules" apply to those methods. Call them whatever you like!

Comment: This makes sense, and a little excursion in the history was useful; however, I'm not sure `mock`s necessarily have something to do in this context, as the question has a sole context of JUnit. Eventually, it seems like there is still nothing so ingrained into daily use, for `@AfterAll`/`@BeforeAll`, as it was in case of `@After` and `@Before`. Thank you.

Comment: The reference to mock setup was merely an example, since many people prepare mocks in a setup method. The lifecycle methods are typically related to a test fixture or subject under test (SUT). So they might also be named something like `prepareDirectory()` and `cleanDirectory()` if the SUT works with a particular directory in the filesystem.